# How to test a site for mobile friendliness?

Tags: html, css, web

I am working on writing my first serious website as a personal project and would like to test it for mobile friendliness and compatibility before I go through the process of actually configuring the FTP, etc. Is there a way to do this using just the files locally on my computer? I've tried to research a way to just upload all the site files and view how everything would look on a mobile browser, but I have not been able to find anything. Or, is there a way to open the HTML files on my phone in a browser, i.e. Chrome?

Comment: Use the emulator feature in devtools?

Comment: You can use https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/?hl=es

Comment: You can use inspect an element from google chrome. It has option for testing for 5-6 phones of different size.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/device-mode/

Answer (score 1):

the best way -> https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/

Google Offers Tips to optimize your site template and a higher quality of mind

Answer (score 0):

You can test your website using google webmaster tool [here](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/).

If you wanted to test it locally then you can try different extension for different browsers.

for chrome [check this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/responsive-web-design-tes/objclahbaimlfnbjdeobicmmlnbhamkg) it will help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to others - http://www.mobilephoneemulator.com/.
And of course, you can test your website with your smartphone.